# Começar a combobox sem nenhum texto

Tags: html

Tenho um select (normalmente chamada de combobox) e queria que não houvesse texto quando executo o site

```
<select>
  <option value="Roupa Desportiva">Roupa Desportiva</option>
  <option value="Futebol">Futebol</option>
  <option value="Basquetebol">Basquetebol</option>
  <option value="Andebol">Andebol</option>
  <option value="Tenis">Tenis</option>
</select>
```

esse é o código que estou a utilizar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

É só deixar o primeiro campo vazio

**Opção 1**

```html
<select>
  <option selected data-default value=""></option>
  <option value="Roupa Desportiva">Roupa Desportiva</option>
  <option value="Futebol">Futebol</option>
  <option value="Basquetebol">Basquetebol</option>
  <option value="Andebol">Andebol</option>
  <option value="Tenis">Tenis</option>
</select>
```

**Opção 2**: Texto de auxilio para o usuário.

```css
select option[data-default] {
  color: #999; /* cor simulando que o campo está desabilitado depois que abre o select */
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected data-default>- Selecione -</option>
  <option value="Roupa Desportiva">Roupa Desportiva</option>
  <option value="Futebol">Futebol</option>
  <option value="Basquetebol">Basquetebol</option>
  <option value="Andebol">Andebol</option>
  <option value="Tenis">Tenis</option>
</select>
```

Comment: é so porque visualmente nao fica bonito e para depois por na base de dados nao quero ter um valor em branco para nao ter de fazer validações

Comment: @JoséGomes Sim entendo. Na verdade o pior ao meu ver é o usuário achar que o campo já está selecionado com uma opção, ou achar que o campo é obrigatório.

Comment: sim por isso é que não queria lá texto... Não existe então outra forma de resolver senão a acima indicada?

Comment: Sim acabei de editar com outra opção

Comment: ok, obrigado pela ajuda @hugocsl

Comment: Tranquilo jovem estamos ai. Inclui um CSS no select agora, então a primeira opção fica meio apagada no combo box, é só um detalhe de usabilidade mesmo. Boa sorete com o projeto!